# Navigation progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

I'm trying to build progress menu bar(similar to one on the piccsy investors http://www.piccsy.com/investors/ )

It measures the height of the page and progresses %.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks,
Nikola.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you have a solution for this issue.

First of all the div:

```
<div id="bar"></div>​
```

Now some styling:

```
body{
    height:4000px;
}

#bar{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
}​
```

And finally the jQuery code:

```
var bar = $('#bar'),
    $window = $(window),
    docHeight = $(document).height(),
    baseX = $window.height() / docHeight * 100;

bar.css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, red '+ baseX +'%, green '+ baseX +'%)');

$window.scroll(function(e) {      
    var x = $window.scrollTop() / docHeight * 100 + baseX;
    bar.css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, red '+ x +'%, green '+ x +'%)');
});
```

​You can find a working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVr8R/).

Note that this only works in Google Chrome, as I have only used `-webkit-linear-gradient`. If you want to make sure it works in all browsers you should add its specific property. You may find useful [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/index.php) for that.

Answer (score 9):

You can use .scroll() to capture scroll events using jquery.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {...})
```

Inside this function you can get scroll height using .scrollTop() function.

```
var height = $(window).scrollTop()
```

once you get the height, you can then set the progress-bar.

You can get page height using this function:

```
$(document).height();
```

So that you can calculate percentage to set progress-bar position.