# Connect a div's width to scrollTop() value with jQuery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a scroll progress bar for a website. Basically, I want the width of a div (with a colored background) to be associated with how far the user has scrolled down.

I'm pretty new to jQuery--it's only my second project. Any ideas on how I could get it to work?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="scroll-progress"></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.scroll-progress {
  width:10px; height:10px;
  background-color:green;
  position:fixed;
  top:0em;
  left:0em;
}
```

and the jQuery I took a hack at:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){

var docHeight = $(document).height();
var scrollDepth = $(window).scrollTop(); 
var scrollPercent = parseFloat(scrollDepth / docHeight) * 100;


  $(".scroll-progress").css(width,scrollPercent);


  });
});
```

Comment: why re-invent http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: so would I just insert scrollPercent as the value?

Comment: looking for something more like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11196440/2472219, but it's not working for me. can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I developed your project a little bit, check this out:
(multiplicator is 103, and not 100, because of difference that the scrollbar height is causing itself)

**http://jsfiddle.net/tdBfD/5/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var ScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var NewWidth = (ScrollTop / docHeight) * 103
        $(".scroll-progress").width(NewWidth);
    });
});
```

Comment: awesome... i literally just figured it out on my own, except for the 103. Thanks!

Comment: as a sidenote (the number "103" can vary a little bit from browser to browser. For example, in Codepen (http://codepen.io/tautcopy/pen/dlyjB) I needed to use 110.